# oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement cast exception

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, classcastexception

I have a problem about casting a `CallableStatement` to `OracleCallableStatement`. It gives `ClassCastException` like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper cannot be cast to
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement
```

And the code is:

```
Connection conn = qdbDataSource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
Connection conn2 = ((WLConnection)conn).getVendorConnection();
try {
    CallableStatement cs = conn2.prepareCall("{ ?=call asr.bsc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
    OracleCallableStatement ocs = (OracleCallableStatement)cs;
// (...)
}
```

I tried to use spring jdbc template, but result was the same.

I am using WebLogic 10.3.2 and the driver class of the datasource is default one. I'm also using the `ojdbc14.jar` in my project, the startup classpath does not include it.

Any ideas?

EDIT: These are the subclasses of the runtime wrapper class:

```
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleCallableStatementWrapper class
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement class
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement class
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement class
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperImpl class
weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperImpl class java.lang.Object
```

Comment: whats the oracle version and why do you need to cast it !!!! i think you dont need it (the cast) you can avoid it i mean

Comment: I am using components which are specified for oracle db. The function that I am trying to call is full of it. So I need Oracle CallableStatement. I think oracle version is not so important in here, because I am not getting the error when trying to connect to it, but getting the callablestatement.

Comment: @shareef he want to use it because OracleCallableStatement offers more methods and is more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It was the ojdbc jar under my lib folder. I am using a statement in weblogic.xml like:

prefer-webinf-classes

And this provides to use the jar files under web-inf/lib in the first place. So when it finds an ojdbc.jar under that folder, it just fits for my application but not for weblogic itself. Because weblogic has its own ojdbc jar under it and somehow, it just extends the OracleCallableStatement class to Wrap them from its own ojdbc jar. Because I have a separate ojdbc jar, at runtime, it could not cast it to my jar's OracleCallableStatement. When I removed the jar under web-inf/lib and gave the responsibility about jdbc connections and statements parts to weblogic, it worked.

Thanks fellas

Answer (score 2):

Cast result of getVendorConnection() to OracleConnection, than use OracleCallableStatement instead of CallableStatement,

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection conn2 = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)(((WLConnection)conn).getVendorConnection());
```

Comment: No, it did not work. It did not surprise me actually, because it does not change anything unless I use a different implementation of the method "prepareCall"

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper cannot be cast to
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement

So i work few weeks ago with `OracleCallableStatement` and i solved it with import `ojdbc6.jar`.

So you just add to your project this file and it offers directly `OracleCallableStatement`,
 `OraclePreparedStatement` etc..

All what you need is `import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;` and it will works.

```
Connection con = null;
OracleCallableStatement cs = null;
try {
   con = OracleDAOFactory.getOracleDatabaseConnection();
   cs = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall(SOME_PROCEDURE);
   ...
}
```

Have look at [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html).

Comment: I had it in my own projects lib folder, and that was the problem dude:) see my answer

Comment: yes, you first create CallableStatement and then you try to cast to OracleCallableStatement but you must create OracleCallableStatement and when you call prepareCall(it returns CallableStatement) then cast..its different. i updated my answer, check it what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, u are right too, but in my implementation, that was not the problem. See my answer if u want. And the way u get the connection is not like mine. I need to get it from weblogic connection pool. I forgot to say that in my question, sorry about that

Comment: yes...this is example from my project how to retrieve connection. just use yours but there is problem with casting callablestatements and im sure this works. so try it. It has nothing in common with connection.

Answer (score -1):

I will give best solution, one approach is using `<wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</ wls:prefer-web-inf-classes >` in *weblogic.xml*. 
If you want true instead of `false` in `web-inf-classes` then another approach is remove *ojdbcXX.jar* in lib folder. While compiling program you can use any *ojdbcXX.jar* in classpath. But while deploying remove *ojdbcXX.jar* from lib. So that weblogic application server will use its own ojdbc and it will run successfully without any error.